# Canvas child does not shift position

Tags: silverlight, canvas, custom-controls, position

Tribe,

I have built a Silverlight custom control, TextBubble, which is an ellipse and textblock inside a grid. I'm adding these text bubbles to a canvas object through code on demand. When I do so, the properties of the TextBubble are set but are not reflected when the objects show up on the canvas.

If I build the same structure manually and add the  to the canvas, canvas.Children.Add(grid), this child shows up correctly.

Using the TextBubble, the text and ellipse show up but the diameter and the X,Y have not bee applied, the bubble shows up in the top left of the canvas.

Thanks for any help,
-AM

Code that works:

```
Grid g = new Grid();
g.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, 100.0);
g.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, 100.0);
Ellipse e = new Ellipse();
e.Width = 50;
e.Height = 50;
e.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
g.Children.Add(e);
TextBlock t = new TextBlock();
t.Text = "TEST";
t.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
t.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center;
g.Children.Add(t);
this.canvas.Children.Add(g);
```

Code that does not:

```
TextBubble bubble = new TextBubble();
bubble.Text = "TEST";
bubble.Diameter = 50;
bubble.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
bubble.X = 100;
bubble.Y = 100;
canvas.Children.Add(bubble);
```

TextBubble object:

```
public class TextBubble : Control {

public TextBubble() {
    this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(TextBubble);
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Text",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(TextBubble),
        new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnTextChanged)));

public static readonly DependencyProperty DiameterProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Diameter",
        typeof(int),
        typeof(TextBubble),
        new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnDiameterChanged)));

public static readonly DependencyProperty FillProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Fill",
        typeof(Brush),
        typeof(TextBubble),
        new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnFillChanged)));

public static readonly DependencyProperty XCoordProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "X",
        typeof(double),
        typeof(TextBubble),
        new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnXCoordChanged)));

public static readonly DependencyProperty YCoordProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Y",
        typeof(double),
        typeof(TextBubble),
        new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnYCoordChanged)));


public string Text {
    get { return (string)this.GetValue(TextProperty); }
    set { base.SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
}

public int Diameter {
    get { return (int)this.GetValue(DiameterProperty); }
    set { base.SetValue(DiameterProperty, value); }
}

public Brush Fill {
    get { return (Brush)this.GetValue(FillProperty); }
    set { base.SetValue(FillProperty, value); }
}

public double X {
    get { return (double)this.GetValue(XCoordProperty); }
    set { base.SetValue(XCoordProperty, value); }
}

public double Y {
    get { return (double)this.GetValue(YCoordProperty); }
    set { base.SetValue(YCoordProperty, value); }
}
}
```

Generic.xml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:X4S.Controls" >
<Style TargetType="local:TextBubble">
    <Setter Property="Text" Value="ABC" />
    <Setter Property="Diameter" Value="50" />
    <Setter Property="X" Value="100.0" />
    <Setter Property="Y" Value="100.0" />
    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="GhostWhite" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:TextBubble">
                <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Canvas.Top="{TemplateBinding Y}" Canvas.Left="{TemplateBinding X}" >
                    <Ellipse Fill="{TemplateBinding Fill}" Width="{TemplateBinding Diameter}" Height="{TemplateBinding Diameter}"/>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Got it!

When adding a new custom control to the canvas child tree we got this extra thing (the TextBubble) wrapped around the grid-textblock-ellipse bundle. Well, the TextBubble object never had its location or size set. So even though the Text and Fill were being applied to the internal controls, those properties were not impacted by the TextBubble's location or size.

Once we applied the same location and size attributes to the TextBubble itself - voila it worked.

The key was this:
    ((Control)canvas.GetDescendant()).GetDescendant().GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty)
    200.0

Which showed that the grid really DID have its location set - but its parent, the TextBubble , did not.

The fix:

```
private static void OnDiameterChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
    TextBubble textBubble = d as TextBubble;
    textBubble.Width = (int)e.NewValue;
    textBubble.Height = (int)e.NewValue;
}

private static void OnLeftChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
    TextBubble textBubble = d as TextBubble;
    textBubble.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, e.NewValue);
}

private static void OnTopChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
    TextBubble textBubble = d as TextBubble;
    textBubble.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, e.NewValue);
}
```

There might be a better way (I'll research it) but this worked.

Comment: Did you try in the constructor of your custom control: this.DataContext = this;

Comment: I did try this.DataContext = this; No help though.

Comment: No need for code here, you control's template can perfectly handle it - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working solution, I've just checked it. Still you've got two choices:
1. Set DataContext in constructor and use regular Bindings
2. Don't set DataContext and use RelativeSource as your source (see the XAML below)

It's not exactly obvious that Canvas.Left & Canvas.Top should be set for the immediate child of canvas, which is local:TextBubble.

```
<Style TargetType="local:TextBubble">
        <Setter Property="Text" Value="ABC" />
        <Setter Property="Diameter" Value="50" />


        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" 
                Value="{Binding Path=Y, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" 
                Value="{Binding Path=X, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />

        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="GhostWhite" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:TextBubble">
                    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" >
                        <Ellipse Fill="{TemplateBinding Fill}" Width="{TemplateBinding Diameter}" Height="{TemplateBinding Diameter}"/>
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: FindAncestor and AncestorType are not available in Silverlight 4.0, apparently. Thanks for the attempt though. I'll go ahead and abandon this method as the bulky method works but is ugly.

Comment: What's strange is that the Text and Fill properties work and are applied to the textblock and ellipse. But the diameter and X,Y values are not. Is there some sort of "update you lazy dog" command to get the canvas to update itself?